# SSL certificate error on deauthorization callback

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ssl-certificate, ssl

Our certificate validates fine on digicert's validation site.

Following error messages are seen in our server side log, when Facebook sends a deauthorization callback in response to the application removal:

```
1326154676 2012.01.09 16:17:56 LOG3[30722:4057095072]: SSL_accept: 14094418: error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
1326154676 2012.01.09 16:17:56 LOG4[30722:4057095072]: SSL_accept error occured for client ip = 69.171.224.250:53589
```

Please note that the SSL handshake seems to work if I use the callback API to register the same server as a "callback" server.

Comment: `Issued To... Organizational Unit: www.digicert.com` — it looks like certificate has been issued by DigiCert for itself. Or it's you stub?

Comment: that's not the case. The OU is not digicert.. Only the issuer is digicert..

Comment: Any update on how you solved the problem? I am running into a similar issue with a StartSSL certificate...

Answer (score 0):

According to https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nodejs/evvmWpjwrQc/9yD7_cEQL0cJ, Node.js may have some issues validating DigiCert and Thawte certificates:

> Looks like these certs don't have a subjectaltname element like most 
>   wildcard certs do.  lib.js assumes wildcard certs will have
>   subjectaltname and doesn't  check the depreciated subject.CN for
>   wildcard match on lines 163 and 
>   166.

It looks like this issue was filed as https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/4255 and a patch has landed — however it's unclear to me if there are any plans to backport the fix to node.js 0.10.